# How to Configure a RetryTemplate in Spring Batch with Java Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-retry, retrypolicy

I am trying to set up a RetryTemplate in Spring Batch, I just cannot find an example on how to add the RetryTemplate into the StepBuilderFactory. I've found this example to set it up in a SpringBoot Application, https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-spring-retry-template but no luck on Spring Batch.

The reason I am trying to use RetryTemplate is to set-up a Exponential BackOffPolicy ([Spring Batch how to configure retry period for failed jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128067/spring-batch-how-to-configure-retry-period-for-failed-jobs)).

I imagine to wire the RetryTemplate would be as simple as setting the RetryTemplate Bean, something like it (modified code from @Mahmoud Ben Hassine answer [Spring Batch how to configure retry period for failed jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128067/spring-batch-how-to-configure-retry-period-for-failed-jobs)):

```
@Bean
public RetryTemplate testExponentialBackoff() throws Exception {
        // configure backoff policy
        ExponentialBackOffPolicy exponentialBackOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        exponentialBackOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000);
        exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2.0);
        exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);

        // configure retry policy
        SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);

        // configure retry template
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(exponentialBackOffPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy);
        return retryTemplate;
    }
```

I am not finding a way to wire it to the StepBuilderFactory .
I would imagine it would be something similar to the "standard" retry:

```
  .faultTolerant()
  .retryLimit(3)
  .retry(ConnectTimeoutException.class)
```

Does anybody have an example/template on how to set it up using Java Configuration?

Any help/example is appreciated. Thx, Markus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to set a custom backoff policy, there is no need to provide an entire `RetryTemplate` for that, you can do it with the `FaultTolerantStepBuilder#backOffPolicy` method, something like:

```
// configure backoff policy
ExponentialBackOffPolicy exponentialBackOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
// customize exponentialBackOffPolicy as needed

Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
        .chunk(5)
        // configure reader/writer etc
        .faultTolerant()
        .backOffPolicy(exponentialBackOffPolicy)
        // set other properties
        .build();
```

Now if you really want to provide a custom `RetryOperations` object, you need to extend the `FaultTolerantStepBuilder` and override the `createRetryOperations` method.

Comment: Thx @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, that is what I am looking for. How to implement the ExponentialBackOffPolicy. Being Spring, I thought it was not going to be difficult to implement/wire.